# php - Get minimum and maximum values from comma separated value ranges

Tags: php

I have simple values ranges as

```
0-50000,100000-250000,250000-500000,1000000,
```

This may be only 0-50000 or 0-50000,100000-250000, or 0-50000,250000-500000, or 1000000,
if 1000000, get max value infinite

In any one of the above mentioned cases selected, i want to get minimum and maximum values.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you done anything yourself yet?

Comment: can somebody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one simple solution using Explode()

```
$val = '0-50000,100000-250000,250000-500000,1000000';
$min = '';
$max = '';

$valExlode=explode(",",$val);

foreach ( $valExlode as $singleVal ) {
   $singleValExplode = explode ("-",$singleVal);
   foreach ( $singleValExplode as $singleUnit ) {
      if ( $min == '' ) {
        $min = (int)$singleUnit;
      }
      if ( $max == '' ) {
        $max = (int)$singleUnit;
      }
      if ( $singleUnit <= $min ) {
        $min = (int)$singleUnit;
      }
      if ( $singleUnit >= $max ) {
        $max = (int)$singleUnit;
      }
  }
}
echo "Minimum: ".$min;
echo "Maximum: ".$max;
```

as #Barmar suggested

Comment: You're doing string comparisons, not numeric comparisons. You should convert everything to `int`.

Comment: But this is not working properly. this giving minimum value 50000 and max value 1000000, But i need min value 0 and max value infinite or say some very big value 100000000000 in the above case.

Comment: when I tested it gave me minimum value 0 and maximum value from this set of values which is 1000000

Comment: i cut copy your code to test. But it is not giving min value 0

Comment: Just not working for 0, changed 0 to 1 and everything working. Thanks